# mrtoybox.co.uk frontend down

Tags: magento-1.9, database, mysql

My configuration menu was down so I used the magento connect to reinstall it and update a few of the other features.
I now can access configuration but have this message on the frontend.

```
There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mrtoybox_mage1.activated_reference' doesn't exist


Trace:
#0 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#4 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#5 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(737): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#6 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#7 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll('SELECT `main_ta...', Array)
#8 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData()
#9 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(752): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#10 [internal function]: Varien_Data_Collection->count()
#11 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/activated/slider/banner.phtml(15): count(Object(Activated_Slider_Model_Resource_Banner_Collection))
#12 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/mrtoybox...')
#13 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#14 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#15 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/community/Activated/Slider/Block/Slider.php(37): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#16 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Activated_Slider_Block_Slider->_toHtml()
#17 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#19 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#21 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#22 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home2/mrtoybox...')
#23 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#24 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#30 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#31 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#32 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#33 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#34 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#35 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#36 /home2/mrtoybox/public_html/mag/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#37 {main}
```

Any ideas on how best to repair.  I use filezilla and the magento backend so keep it user friendly please.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is unable to find your 3rd party extension table `activated_reference`.

Disable the extension `Activated_Slider` temporarily to bring your site up. Open `app/etc/modules/Activated_Slider.xml` file and replace `true` with `false`. And clear the cache by removing all the files present at `var/cache/` directory.